# How to execute external program from custom directory in Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, com, silverlight-5.0

In order to execute external applications from Silverlight app, you need to:

1. Run out-of-browser
2. Have elevated trust permissions

To execute such applications, you can do something like this

```
public static void EjecutaEXE(string ruta)
{
    using (dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"))
    {
        shell.Run(@ruta);
    }
}
```

I have found that I am only able to run such application from the Windows directory, Am I missing something? seems pointless such limitation.

This WORKS:

```
EjecutaEXE("C:/Windows/myAwesomeApp.exe")
```

This does NOT WORK:

```
EjecutaEXE("C:/myfolder/myAwesomeApp.exe")
```

There are no errors or exceptions, it just does nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't you use backslash (\\) instead of forward slash (/) in Your Call? Remember then to put double backslash or add @ in front of the string for the path.

Comment: @Peaceman71 No, you don't, as I pointed out, the first example works (you can test in your Windows explorer, that you can perfectly navigate with /). The @ for literal is included in function already. Another key point is that the FileNotFound Exception is rised if the file is not found, and it is not the case here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience With the code you presented, but as an alternative this should work:

```
public enum ShowCommands : int
{
    SW_HIDE = 0,
    SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1,
    SW_NORMAL = 1,
    SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2,
    SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3,
    SW_MAXIMIZE = 3,
    SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4,
    SW_SHOW = 5,
    SW_MINIMIZE = 6,
    SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7,
    SW_SHOWNA = 8,
    SW_RESTORE = 9,
    SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10,
    SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11,
    SW_MAX = 11
}

[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(
        IntPtr hwnd,
        string lpOperation,
        string lpFile,
        string lpParameters,
        string lpDirectory,
        ShowCommands nShowCmd);

public static void ExecuteMyCode(string filePath)
{
    IntPtr retval = ShellExecute(System.IntPtr.Zero, string.Empty, filePath, string.Empty, string.Empty, ShowCommands.SW_NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, did you consider the title question is marked for Silverlight?, this answer looks like non-silverlight environment. And, if it is silverlight compatible, where exactly  should I put it (because as a method, didnt work)?

Comment: This is a working example from a Silverlight 5 Application. The second parameter can be "open", "print", "printto" etc. so you can even use this to control how the file shall behave in the called program. If you make a class file and put the first code Block in there, and then make a function With the last line in (the call), this should work.  At least it does in my application...

Comment: Got it, "ShowCommands" can not be found, what directives or references are required? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, it works exactly as my attempt, perfectly on Windows folder, but on a custom one does not, I will check my setup then. Thanks again.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work for you. Hopefully you figure it out. Maybe it has something to do with access rights on the folder?

Comment: Just tested on another computer, same result, then I found this "However, trusted applications cannot access non-user folders except through the OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog classes." here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @nxgtrturbo Was your upvoted comment at all relevant in this scenario?